# Was Microsoft Account Recovery Code de-emphasized, or has it always been?

Tags: account-recovery, microsoft-account, user-documentation

I know [this feature](https://askleo.com/microsoft-account-recovery-code-what-why-instructions/) still exists, because I learned about it today in Microsoft Account -> Security -> Security -> Security Settings.

I tried searching `Microsoft Account Recovery Code` on [support.microsoft.com](https://support.microsoft.com) and [Google web search](https://www.google.com).  In the top results, there was nothing about Microsoft Account Recovery Code from support.microsoft.com.

However, it seems there is no documentation?  Has the documentation been removed in order to de-emphasize the feature, possibly as preparation for removing this "Generate a new code" link?  Or, has it never been in the documentation?

Or, is it documented and my searches just failed?  If so, where?

### full context

I need to set up Two-step verification, and have ways to recover it.  I need a good understanding of how recovery works.  I haven't touched this service for a *long* time, so I don't know what to expect.

I have an adequately safe place to store a recovery code.

Comment: This question was bumped by an answer that was deleted for not being an answer. There is a site that is specialized in security : [security.se]. I wonder if the active users from that site might help with this. Here, [tag:microsoft-account] only has 20 questions.

Comment: security.stackexchange.com is a bit weird. It's scoped to "Information Security professionals". Sadly I'm not currently either paid or actively working in IT. I think the key distinction here is that I'm very much asking for my own account. I'm not trying to support anyone else to use this feature.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think that they are very open to answering questions from nonprofessionals. As you have the association bonus, you might ask on their Meta what they suggest to do concerning this question. As cross-posting is not allowed, I hope to come and post an answer here, give you guidance about how to post a follow-up question there or clarify the site audience and scope.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to review the search tips if you are still looking for an answer to this question. Several years ago, Google launched a [MOOC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Massive_open_online_course) led by [Daniel M. Russell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_M._Russell), and there is a Google Search article, [How to search on Google](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/134479?hl=en).

Start with a basic search. Instead of `[Microsoft Account Recovery Code]`, begin with `[recovery code]`. Look to learn about the subject, look for related, synonyms, and broader terms. Look for specialized sites.

Among Google tips,

1. Try the Stack Exchange Global Search https://stackexchange.com/search?q=recovery+code
2. Try this site search https://webapps.stackexchange.com/search?q=recovery+code
3. Try Information Security Stack Exchange https://security.stackexchange.com/search?q=recovery+code
4. Try Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?search=recovery+code

The above links include `[recovery code]`. Remember that starting with a basic search aims to learn about the topic to refine your search later. Each search engine has its search features.

Remember that the Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange platform has tags, but remember that tags' meanings might vary from site to site.

Once you find a webpage, if you find hints that it might be updated and the information that you are looking for was removed or renamed, look at [The Internet Archive](https://archive.org), more specifically their [Wayback Machine](https://archive.org/web/) for captures of the webpage.

Comment: Hmm, it's specifically Microsoft documentation I'm interested in. It'll have "microsoft" on the page. I've double-checked that "recovery code" doesn't find it on support.microsoft.com. And "Microsoft Account" is the correct term, because it's what all their non-relevant results used in their current documentation.